# How to seed data using db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have spent a while looking for the answer but perhaps I dont understand the principles. I have a table called user which has two fields called name and value. I have migrated this fine and created a model and controller as well.

My migration file looks like:

```
 class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.integer :value

       t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end
```

I am using the following to seed the data

```
Users.create!([{ name: 'Chicago' , value:'12'}, { name: 'Coppo' , value:'15'} , { name: 'Bilbo' , value:'13' }, { name: 'Steve' , value:'12'}, { name: 'Shazza' , value:'11'}])
```

followed by

```
 rake db:seed
```

But I keep on getting the same error of:

```
 NameError: uninitialized constant Users
```

Comment: Model names are singular, try `User.create(...)`

Comment: I get this error:    NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object

Comment: Hang on now it works if I capitalise User. Learning point db:seed create creates data for the model which needs a capital letter

Comment: You should read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html (and probably the rest of the site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing *Naming Conventions*.
For a class `User`, you should have a database table called `users`.

**Database Table** - Plural (e.g., users, user_profiles).
**Model Class** - Singular with the first letter of each word capitalized (e.g., User, UserProfile).

Model actions would be:

```
User.create(Hash)
UserProfile.create(Hash)
```

Change your seed code into this:

```
User.create!([{ name: 'Chicago' , value:'12'}, { name: 'Coppo' , value:'15'} , { name: 'Bilbo' , value:'13' }, { name: 'Steve' , value:'12'}, { name: 'Shazza' , value:'11'}])
```